# Best way for custom filtering in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slickgrid

In my app, I have a SlickGrid data grid and I would like to support filtering on it.

I went through these examples:

- [SlickGrid example 4:
  Model](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html)
- [Using fixed header row for quick
  filters](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html)

I am not interested in the UI of those two examples. I want to provide a filter icon on the column header and when a user clicks it, a drop down should popup with distinct items in the column and checking or unchecking these should filter the column by them.

I can code all this up on my own but as there is some filtering supported in SlickGrid, is there any way I can change the UI as I described earlier?

I am assuming that many people must have already thought in that direction.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did it using my own coding..there is no inbuilt way of providing a filter like what you want..

You have to first create a button in every header column clicking which will show/hide the panel in which all columns with checkboxes will be there...

Now when you check/uncheck any CB you need to trigger the updateFilter function which is called on keypress in the examples links which you have posted and then check if the entered string is in the columns which are checked(all columns if nothing checked or whatever is your approach) and return true or false accordingly